# Are there any results on density in $L^p$ spaces with $0<p<1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

Are there any results on density in $L^p$ spaces with $0<p<1$? For example, $C_0^\infty$ dense in $L^p$ with $p\geq 1$. Now about $L^p$ spaces with $0<p<1$, are there any notable density results?

Comment: what is the topology you are considering on these spaces?

Comment: @rubikscube09: presumably is the one defined by the metric $d(f, g)=\int|f-g|^p\,d\mu$. For $X$ locally compact Haussdorf,  integable smiple functions and functions in $C_{00}(X)$ are still dense in $L_p$ ($0<p<1$) by monotone convergence and by Lusin's theorem. The case $X=\mathbb{R}^d$ is probably what the OP has in mind.

Comment: @Ilovemat: Density in these spaces is similar to that in $L_p$ spaces with $p\geq1$. The reason is that $t\mapsto t^p$, $t\geq0$ is still monotone increasing for $0<p<1$; thus. the proofs of density of simple functions, continuous functions of compact support, etc hold for these spaces (under the assumptions that the intrinsic measure $\mu$ is a Radon measure (regular)). A simple discussion of these spaces and the pathologies they carry our own Conrad has a nice presentation [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much @OliverDiaz for your excellent comments!